# scrollbar with drag effect in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I need to implement scrolling bars in form. 
This is for web users by clicking on scrolling bar, they can navigate. Scrollbar class in flutter works for touch device, but not with mouse based input. I've tried using "draggable_scrollbar" library from pub.dev, however it only accepts ListView as child.
My code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('My form'),
    ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Scrollbar(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(...),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this can work for you.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text('My form'),
     ),
     body: Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
       child: Scrollbar(
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
           child: DraggableScrollbar.rrect(
             controller: myScrollController,
             child: ListView.builder(
               controller: myScrollController,
               itemCount: 1,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                 return Form();
               },
             ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy.. I have tried earlier with same code, but not working. After setting item count 1, it works.. thanks so much.