# Is there an equivalent to `overflow:scroll` in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to access the native scrollbar of the browser (check out the thing on the right side here). Normally, if the content of a widget exceeds the viewport, Flutter throws an error like: `A RenderFlex overflowed by 445 pixels on the bottom.` Is there a setting or something that can tell Flutter web to just make that particular widget scrollable? If we use the Scrollbar widget than it's not draggable, and the DraggableScrollbar widget looks very weird and the implementation code is way over my pay grade. I just want the normal scrollbar that my grandparents are used to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrollbar with drag effect in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230354/scrollbar-with-drag-effect-in-flutter)

Comment: That one is not draggable, chief. But the one below does answer my question (which is why I marked it as such). Thanks for showing up tho. Are you wearing a mask and staying safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the full steps because maybe someone is going to use the `DraggableScrollbar` widget for the first time.

**1.** Add this to the `pubspec.yaml` dependencies:

```
draggable_scrollbar: ^0.0.4
```

**2.** Import the package:

```
import 'package:draggable_scrollbar/draggable_scrollbar.dart';
```

**3.** Define a `ScrollController`:

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

**4.** Usage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: DraggableScrollbar.rrect(
            controller: _scrollController,
            heightScrollThumb: 100,
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemExtent: 150.0,
              itemCount: 50,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Card(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(index.toString()),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I see a bunch of Widgets nested inside each other. Where exactly is the place that I get to put my actual content? Is it inside the last Container?

Comment: What is the widget that you want it to be scrollable? You need to replace the `ListView.builder` with that widget(set the child of the `ScrollableBar.rrect` to the scrollable widget). @AndreiȚăranu

Comment: I just want a column with a bunch of containers in it that will scroll for as long as it has space to render. So I guess a SingleChildScrollView would work instead of the ListView. And I could give it the same _scrollController. Correct?

Comment: Wrap the containers with a `ListView` and set the `ListView` as the child of the `ScrollableBar.rrect`. @AndreiȚăranu

Comment: And don't forget to set the controller for the `ListView`. Let me know if you faced any problems. @AndreiȚăranu